# how to count the element with the same index?

Tags: python, pandas

I have to get the numbers of counties of every state from a CSV file and then return which state has the most counties. But I don't know how to count the element that is under the de same index

csv file:
[image]

I tried to use .count() and numerate() but returns me an error key error: "Alabama"

this is the code I used to create the actual data frame from the CSV file

```
import pandas as PD

census = pd.read_csv('census.csv')
counties = pd.DataFrame({'State':census['STNAME'],'County':census['CTYNAME'],
         'populations':census['CENSUS2010POP'],'population 2010': census['POPESTIMATE2010'], 
         'population 2015': census['POPESTIMATE2015']})
counties = counties.set_index(['State', 'County'])
```

Comment: so you want to know how many counties each state  has? if so, do `counties.reset_index().groupby('State').size()`

Comment: @Yuca do you really need `reset_index()`?

Comment: not sure actually how groupby behaves with multtiindex, so I took the safety route

Answer (score 0):

## try:

```
counties.groupby(['State','County']).agg('count')
```

## instead of:

```
counties = counties.set_index(['State', 'County']).count()
```